# ListPreference no selection. How to?

Tags: android, listpreference

I have a ListPreference and want to verify if there is no selection to make some code/treatement. How can i do this ?
I have this to verify the selection:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(choice) == 0) {
```

What code to verify if not selection?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a preference selected for this `ListPreference`, then it will be saved in your `SharedPreferences`. You can test against this value by doing something like this:

```
private Boolean prefHasSelection(String prefId){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String yourPref = sp.getString(prefId, null);
    return (yourPref != null);
}

prefHasSelection("yourPrefId"); // returns true if something is set
```

You could call this method at any point in your application lifecycle to determine if the preference has been set.